# SwiftUI - Multi-Lined text macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

How does one display Text UI elements with multiple wrapped lines within a SwiftUI list.

The following code produces the following [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIK2M.png), and I can't seem to find a way to make this work as intended.

```
let test = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non.  Lorem END"


var body: some View {
    List(){
        Text(test).lineLimit(nil)
        Divider()
        Text(test).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        Divider()
        Text(test)
    }
}
```

---

`.lineLimit(nil)` fails to work

---

`.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` also fails to work

Comment: Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2 and Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 - all three variants give **same** correctly wrapped text.

Comment: what do you mean by "as intended" ??

Comment: use ScrollView instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update: fixed!

Re-tested with Xcode 13.4 / macOS 12.4 - `Text` just works, below workaround not needed anymore.

#### Original

Ok, here is for macOS (added tag as well for better visibility), not by-default, but achievable for `List` as well, if needed List's performance, etc. and without any hardcoding.

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.3

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { gp in
        List {
            Text(self.test)
                .padding(.trailing)
                .frame(width: gp.size.width)
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As always great answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ScrollView, not List

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let test = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Donec enim diam vulputate ut pharetra. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non.  Lorem END"


    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(test).lineLimit(1).padding()
            Text(test).lineLimit(3).padding()
            Text(test).padding()
        }.frame(maxWidth: 400)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]